# Index exceeds array bounds. MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

I'm trying to apply Jacobi method under MATLAB and write the code normally but keep getting the same error "Index exceeds array bounds." even I don't see clearly that there is an  error in my code hope you really help me to recognize the problem
here's my code ,the error is at the highlighted line in the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db6Z9.png)

Comment: Please copy-paste the code directly into your post. [See here for the reasons we don't like images of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Oh, and copy-paste the full error message with the stack trace. You can [edit] your post at any time to improve it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank u so much , i agree sometimes when I write the code I got some issues of publishing it that's why

Answer (score 0):

Run "dbstop if all error" and then run your code again. The debugger will stop when it hits the error, and you'll probably be able to spot that one of you array indices is out of bounds.

Comment: thank u so much for this help , it got fixed